# Nginx URL rewrite with space

Tags: redirect, nginx

I have a URL /test/space which i want to redirect it to the correct URL /test/
on nginx

I tried 
rewrite ^/test/%20 /test redirect;

without results any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The URL encoded characters have already been decoded by the time it gets to the `rewrite` statement. You just need to enclose it in quotes:

```
rewrite "^/test/ " /test redirect;
```